# Is Murasugi's conjecture still open?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, open-problems

Normalize the Alexander polynomial (in $t$) so that the positive and negative exponents are balanced.  For example in the Conway normalization, make the substitution $z = t^{1/2} - t^{-1/2}$.  The trefoil gives $t^{-1} - 1 + t$.

> **Conjecture:**  Suppose that $K$ is an alternating knot.  Then the sequence of absolute values of the coefficients is unimodal.  Specifically, if $\Delta_K(t) = \sum_i a_i t^i$, then $|a_0| \ge |a_1| \ge |a_2| \ge \cdots$.

This is a conjecture due to Murasugi, I believe.  Where is it written?  Has this been proved or disproved?

Comment: I think the knot has to be alternating.

Comment: There's definately a lot of non-alternating counter-examples to this conjecture in the knot tables. 

Comment: Is it possible to rephrase this conjecture as about coefficients of Tutte polynomials of graphs?

Comment: There was recent progress on Fox's conjecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.04733. (This paper is sort of along the lines of what I suggested in the previous comment - using a version of the Tutte polynomial for a certain kind of graphical representation of the knot, and then applying the powerful machinery of Lorentzian polynomials.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't Hosokawa prove (1958, Osaka J. Math) that the Alexander polynomial of a knot can be any integral Laurent polynomial $p(t)$ such that $p(t^{-1}) = p(t)$ and $p(1) = \pm 1$?

If that's right, then according to Hosokawa, $2t^{-2}+t^{-1}-7+t+2t^2$ would be the Alexander polynomial of a knot, contradicting this conjecture.

It's been a while but I think you construct these knots very explicitly using ribbon diagrams -- Rolfsen's knots and links, also Kawauchi's big survey book should have the construction.

Comment: Why is this an answer? The conjecture is about ALTERNATING knots...

Comment: Alternating was edited-in after I posted this answer.  As Sivek mentions, apparently the conjecture is still open.

Comment: Ah, OK. It just looks a little strange, but maybe this exchange will deconfuse future generations.

Answer (score 18):

It's actually a conjecture of Fox, sometimes known as the trapezoidal conjecture: the absolute values of the coefficients of $\Delta_K(t)$ are nonincreasing if K is an *alternating* knot.  I think the original citation is Fox, "Some problems in knot theory."

Murasugi apparently proved the conjecture for alternating algebraic knots -- see "On the Alexander polynomial of alternating algebraic knots", MR0802722, which doesn't seem to be online -- and Ozsváth and Szabó proved it for genus 2 alternating knots in "Heegaard Floer homology and alternating knots," arXiv:0209149, but it's still open in general.

Comment: Do you know why Fox made this conjecture?  I wonder if there's a reason to suspect it, or if it's a correlation from loads of computations. 

Answer (score 2):

See also [this paper by Jong](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-46/issue-2/Alexander-polynomials-of-alternating-knots-of-genus-two/ojm/1245415674.full) which reproves the Ozsvath-Szabo result combinatorially, using Stoimenow's generators for knots of canonical genus 2.
The interesting question which is lurking in the background is the characterization of Alexander polynomials of alternating knots.